# update gmail contacts C# exception

Tags: c#, gmail

I am trying to update gmail contacts info

```
Contact updatedContact = contact.Contact;
updatedContact.Content = "Contact information for " + contact.Contact.Name.FullName;
Uri feedUri = new Uri(ContactsQuery.CreateContactsUri("default"));
RequestSettings rs2 = new RequestSettings("CreateContacts", username, password);
ContactsRequest cr = new ContactsRequest(rs2);
Contact createdContact = cr.Update(updatedContact);
```

but I got that exception

```
"execution of request failed http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/"mail"/full/..."
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue with your machine running the code, it may work on other machines.

If you are behind a proxy, here is an article on how to setup properly with proxies:

http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/proxy_setup.html

Comment: I read that article, and tried to use that code (but I could not), I do not have service or factory, I can not map that code to mine.

Answer (score 0):

I find the reason of the exception

there is no problems appears when names are updated like that

```
contact.Name.FullName = value;
```

but when update phone numbers like that the above exception appears

```
contact.Phonenumbers.Add(new Google.GData.Extensions.PhoneNumber(value));
```

it appears that gmail return the same exception regardless of what error had happened, how can I understand that from just "execution of request failed", that is quite annoying.

I hope they add some details, though I do not know what is wrong in updating phone numbers like that.